# Run SQL Server Express on a local machine and access it with management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I was taking class in college, I only had to download Management Studio and connect a SQL server from the university. Howevere, I'm no longer in that class and would like to practice on my local machine. I've installed SQL Server replication on my local machine, but I don't know how to access it using Management Studio. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've installed SQL Express under the default instance (SQLEXPRESS). To connect via SSMS, you should use the machine name (or localhost, if it is the local machine), backslash, and the instance name as the server name.
So in your case, try entering localhost\SQLEXPRESS.

As for the authentication, unless you specifically enabled Mixed Mode Authentication during the installation, you only have Windows Authentication available. You likely added the account you used during the installation as an administrator, so you should be able to run SSMS as that user, and select Windows Authentication to access your sever.

Comment: should i use the following in my ASP webpage to access the site?

Dim mstrConnection As String = "workstation id=COMPUTER; packet size = 4096; data source = localhost\SQLEXPRESS; integrated security = false; user id=x309-PC\x309; password="

Comment: A good resource for finding this information is http://www.connectionstrings.com/
All you should need is "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" for SQL authentication. If you're talking ASP.NET, you should embed this in the web.config file, rather than in the page itself. If you want to pursue this further, you should probably open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Replication is found in the main tree of SSMS. You will need 2 separate instances installed on the machine to be able to replicate between them. With SQL Express, you can only be a subscriber. To create a publication, you need to install SQL standard, workgroup, enterprise, etc.

Comment: I've installed an instance named SQLExpress, but I don't know how to access it when I run management studio

Comment: You can't access it because there is no replication available in express.

Comment: Just to add that the developer version gives you all of the features of Enterprise, and is fairly inexpensive (~ $45).